# SQL split number over date range

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date-range

I have a table with, for example this data

```
ID |start_date  |end_date   |amount
---|------------|-----------|-------
a1 |2013-12-01  |2014-03-31 |100
```

Iwant to have a query that split the dates so I have the amount splitted out over the year like this :

```
ID |org_start_date  |org_end_date   |new_start_date  |new_end_date    |amount
---|----------------|---------------|----------------|----------------|-------
a1 |2013-12-01      |2014-03-31     |2013-12-01      |2013-12-31      |25
a1 |2013-12-01      |2014-03-31     |2014-01-01      |2014-03-31      |75
```

The 25 in 2013 is because 2013 has one month and 75 in 2014 because this has 3 months

Is there a way to do this in T-SQL?

Thx in advance!

Comment: I don't understand how you are splitting the data?

Comment: Split by year? Do you need to split the start and end date in one year?

Comment: @DavidG by months and split values over months, so it's 4 months, 100/4 = monthly amount, then add month by year

Comment: And how do you know to give 25 to the first month and then the 2nd row is 3 months?

Comment: @DavidG month 1 is in 2013, the next 3 count as 2014

Comment: amount is not the problem, I just can do that with an datediff and calculate the amount for a day. It's more the split based upon years

Comment: Will there only ever be two years (hence two rows involved) or could you have 1 or 3 years/rows or more?

Comment: No, can be 3 or more

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `spt_values` table to create a calendar table, then join to your table to split date range into any part you want.

If split by year and divide amount by months you could:

```
with dates as
(
select number,DATEADD(day,number,'20130101') as dt
    from master..spt_values
    where number between 0 and 1000 AND TYPE='P'
)
select
    m.start_date as org_start_date,
    m.end_date as org_end_date,
    min(d.dt) as new_start_date,
    max(d.dt) as new_end_date,
    m.amount*count(distinct month(d.dt))/(datediff(month,m.start_date,m.end_date)+1) as amount
from 
    MonthSplit m
join
    dates d
on 
    d.dt between m.start_date and m.end_date
group by 
    m.start_date, m.end_date, year(d.dt),m.amount
```

Here is the [SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ae78a/2/0).

Comment: unfortunately this doesn't work when start and end have more than one year between. For example 2011 and 2014

Comment: You could change the number 1000 to what you need. Here is the demo(http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/d61051/1)

Comment: Here is a link about numbers table(http://sqlblog.com/blogs/adam_machanic/archive/2006/07/12/you-require-a-numbers-table.aspx). There are more ways of creating numbers table you could learn in the comments .

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution using a numbers table:

[SQL Fiddle Example](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/bb719/10/0)

```
DECLARE @STARTYR INT = (SELECT MIN(YEAR([Start Date])) FROM Table1)
DECLARE @ENDYR INT = (SELECT MAX(YEAR([End Date])) FROM Table1)

SELECT [Id]
     , @STARTYR + Number AS [Year]
     , CASE WHEN YEAR([Start Date]) < @STARTYR + Number 
            THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @STARTYR - 1900 + Number,0) 
            ELSE [Start Date] END AS [Start]
     , CASE WHEN YEAR([End Date]) > @STARTYR + Number 
            THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @STARTYR - 1900 + Number + 1,0) 
            ELSE [End Date] END AS [End]
     , DATEDIFF(MONTH,CASE WHEN YEAR([Start Date]) < @STARTYR + Number 
                           THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @STARTYR - 1900 + Number,0) 
                           ELSE [Start Date] END
                     ,CASE WHEN YEAR([End Date]) > @STARTYR + Number 
                           THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @STARTYR - 1900 + Number + 1,0) 
                           ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(MONTH,1,[End Date])),0) END) AS [Months]
     , DATEDIFF(MONTH,[Start Date],[End Date]) + 1 [Total Months]
     , ([Amount] / (DATEDIFF(MONTH,[Start Date],[End Date]) + 1)) 
       *
       DATEDIFF(MONTH,CASE WHEN YEAR([Start Date]) < @STARTYR + Number 
                           THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @STARTYR - 1900 + Number,0) 
                           ELSE [Start Date] END
                     ,CASE WHEN YEAR([End Date]) > @STARTYR + Number 
                           THEN DATEADD(YEAR, @STARTYR - 1900 + Number + 1,0) 
                           ELSE DATEADD(MONTH,DATEDIFF(MONTH,0,DATEADD(MONTH,1,[End Date])),0) END) AS [Proportion]

FROM Numbers
LEFT JOIN Table1 ON YEAR([Start Date]) <= @STARTYR + Number
                 AND YEAR([End Date]) >= @STARTYR + Number


WHERE Number <= @ENDYR - @STARTYR
```

Answer (score 0):

It's very similar to this question:

**[Split date range into one row per month in sql server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269917/split-date-range-into-one-row-per-month-in-sql-server)**

Although you are doing grouping by year, so based on that answer you can modify it to do what you want by adding `MIN`, `MAX` to your date values and grouping by the `YEAR()`:

### [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/019c1/2)

**Schema Setup**:

```
CREATE TABLE MonthSplit
    ([ID] varchar(2), [start_date] datetime, [end_date] datetime, [amount] int)
;

INSERT INTO MonthSplit
    ([ID], [start_date], [end_date], [amount])
VALUES
    ('a1', '2013-12-01 00:00:00', '2014-03-31 00:00:00', 100),
    ('a2', '2013-10-01 00:00:00', '2015-05-01 00:00:00', 400)
;
```

**Recursive CTE to group by Year**:

```
WITH cte AS
(SELECT ID
      , start_date
      , end_date
      , start_date AS from_date
      , DATEADD(day, day(start_date)* -1 + 1, start_date) AS first_of_month
 FROM MonthSplit
 UNION ALL
 SELECT ID
     , start_date
     , end_date
     , DATEADD(month,1,first_of_month)
     , DATEADD(month,1,first_of_month)
  FROM cte
  WHERE DATEADD(month,1,from_date) < end_date
)
SELECT ID as ID, 
       min(start_date) as org_start_date, 
       min(end_date) as org_end_date, 
       min(from_date) AS new_start_date,
       CASE when max(end_date) < DATEADD(month,1,max(first_of_month)) THEN
           max(end_date)
       ELSE
           DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(month,1,max(first_of_month)))
       END AS new_end_date
FROM cte
group by year(from_date), ID
```

**[Results](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/019c1/2/0)**:

```
| ID | ORG_START_DATE    | ORG_END_DATE   | NEW_START_DATE    | NEW_END_DATE      |
|----|-------------------|----------------|-------------------|-------------------|
| a1 | December, 01 2013 | March, 31 2014 | December, 01 2013 | December, 31 2013 |
| a1 | December, 01 2013 | March, 31 2014 | January, 01 2014  | March, 31 2014    |
| a2 |  October, 01 2013 | May, 01 2015   | October, 01 2013  | December, 31 2013 |
| a2 |  October, 01 2013 | May, 01 2015   | January, 01 2014  | December, 31 2014 |
| a2 |  October, 01 2013 | May, 01 2015   | January, 01 2015  | April, 30 2015    |
```

Comment: This has problems if your dates span more than 2 years.

Comment: Actually I think it's with more than one row not multiple years: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/019c1/1/0

Comment: @bendataclear Just added grouping by ID in updated post

Comment: unfortunatly this gives a recursionerror. Think my dates are to far apart.. "The statement terminated. The maximum recursion 100 has been exhausted before statement completion."

Answer (score 0):

I don't have a ready made SQL for you but just a thought to solve this problem. If you have some experience with SQL it won't be hard to express it in SQL.

You could do this by defining a reference table for the months that are between your begin and end date:

```
ID    |   month       |   year  |   month start   |  month end    |   count |
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
1001  |   dec-2013    |   2013  |   1-12-2013     |   31-12-2013  |     1   |
1001  |   jan-2014    |   2014  |   1-1-2014      |   31-1-2014   |     1   |
1001  |   feb-2014    |   2014  |   1-2-2014      |   28-2-2014   |     1   |
1001  |   mar-2014    |   2014  |   1-3-2014      |   31-3-2014   |     1   |
```

Maybe you already have such a time ref table in your DWH.

When you join (with a between statement) your table with the record that contains the start and end date per row, with this reference table, you'll have the split from 1 row to the number of months contained in the range correct. The count column will help you to get the split ratio per year right by grouping over the year afterwards (like : 1/4 for 2013 and 3/4 for 2014). You'll have to apply the ratio to the field 'amount' that you want to split up.