# Merge two records date if dates are continuous and key values are same

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, date

I have two different scenarios. In the first scenario I need something like:

```
create table test
(
ItemID int,
ItemStartDate datetime,
ItemEndDate datetime,
itemType varchar(100)
)
```

Table `test`:

```
ItemID  ItemStartDate  ItemEndDate  itemType
------  -------------  -----------  --------
item_1  1/1/2011       3/2/2011     value A
item_1  3/3/2011       12/31/2011   value A
item_2  1/3/2011       12/31/2011   value B
```

It should show only two records:

```
ItemID  ItemStartDate  ItemEndDate  itemType
------  -------------  -----------  --------
item_1  1/1/2011       12/31/2011   value A
item_2  1/1/2011       12/31/2011   value B
```

Scenario 2.
Here I would like to split data value to separate year periods if it's across multiple years.

Table `test`

```
create table #Scenario_2
(
ItemID int,
priceStartDate datetime,
priceEndDate datetime,
price int
)

item  startdate  enddate     value
----  ---------  ----------  -----
11    1/1/2011   5/4/2013    500
12    7/1/2013   11/12/2013  600
```

It should show like

```
item  startdate  enddate     value
----  ---------  ----------  -----
11    1/1/2011   12/31/2011  500
11    1/1/2012   12/31/2012  500
11    1/1/2013   5/4/2013    500
12    7/1/2013   11/12/2013  600
```

Please advise how I can achieve this.

Comment: Please add your table column definition to the question and edit the sample data to reflect the columns, and know that using `--` will make it look like a comment, so separate columns with whitespaces instead.

Comment: i have added table definition.

Comment: For scenario1 you could see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/26273819/3630826).

Comment: i am getting null in enddate by using this solution even though there is enddate in source data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For scenario1 you could see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26273819/3630826).

For scenario2 there also have a [similar answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26525142/3630826) you could reference.

But your question can be simplified like this:

```
with dates as
(
select number,cast(ltrim(number*10000+1231) as date) as dt
    from master..spt_values
    inner join 
        (select min(year(startdate)) as s_year
               ,max(year(enddate))  as e_year
         from Scenario_2) as y
    on number between y.s_year and y.e_year AND TYPE='P'
)
select 
    s.item
   ,case when year(dt) = year(startdate) 
         then startdate
         else dateadd(year,-1,dateadd(day,1,dt)) end  --or cast(ltrim(year(dt)*10000+101) as date)
   ,case when year(dt) = year(enddate)
         then enddate
         else dt end
   ,s.value
from 
    Scenario_2 s
inner join 
    dates d
on 
    d.number between year(s.startdate) and year(s.enddate)
```

<kbd>[SQL FIDDLE DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/7889a/6)</kbd>

Comment: i am getting null in enddate by using this solution even though there is enddate in source data

Comment: I found scenario 1 logic from somewhere else and scenario 2 logic you gave worked fine. Thank you so much.

Comment: Can you show me those input data can get null in enddate with this solution? You can use Sql fiddle.

Answer (score 1):

Try this. from your question this is what i understood!!

```
SCENARIO 2
----------
CREATE TABLE #datt
  (
     itemid   int,startd DATE,endat  DATE,price int
  )

INSERT INTO #datt
VALUES      (11,'2011-01-01','2013-05-04',500),
            (12,'2013-7-1','2013-11-12',600)

;WITH cte
     AS (SELECT itemid,
                 startd st,
                case when year(endat)<> YEAR(startd) then Dateadd(yy, Year(startd) - 1899, -1)
                else endat end ed,price
         FROM   #datt
         UNION ALL
         SELECT a.itemid,
                Dateadd(yy, 1, st),
                CASE
                  WHEN Dateadd(yy, 1, ed) > b.endat THEN b.endat
                  ELSE Dateadd(yy, 1, ed)
                END,a.price
         FROM   cte a
                JOIN #datt b
                  ON a.itemid = b.itemid
                     AND a.ed < b.endat)
SELECT *
FROM   cte order by itemid,st
```

Comment: This seems does not working for me when i join table based on id and item value. please advise.

Comment: @Bavi - In SCENARIO 2 output u didn't mention any item value column. If you want it can be added

Comment: how can i add it? because in my case when i try to add it its giving wrong result with all records with 1/1 to 12/31 instead for some dates if its starts from middle of the year or ends at middle of the year

Comment: @Bavi update your question with proper expected output!!

Comment: @Pradeep, +1, you are persistent.