# split one row to multiple row in oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have a simple select query that has this result:

```
first_date | last_date  | outstanding
14/01/2015 | 14/04/2015 | 100000
```

I want to split it to be

```
first_date | last_date  | period     | outstanding 
14/01/2015 | 31/01/2015 | 31/01/2015 | 100000 
01/02/2015 | 28/02/2015 | 28/02/2015 | 100000
01/03/2015 | 31/03/2015 | 31/03/2015 | 100000
01/04/2015 | 14/04/2015 | 31/04/2015 | 100000
```

Please show me how to do it simply, without using function/procedure, object and cursor.

Comment: You can check this - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20269917/split-date-range-into-one-row-per-month-in-sql-server

Comment: Please search stachoverflow next time before you post a question, you'd be amazed how many times the same question is asked by different people

Comment: sorry, my english is not good, i have hard time to find the keyword for googling it, thanks

Comment: i dont understand it, so i simply copy paste it in my toad and it show error PLS-00103 encountered the symbol @

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
WITH my_query_result AS(
  SELECT date '2015-01-14' as first_date , date '2015-04-14' as last_date,
         10000 as outstanding
  FROM dual
)
SELECT  greatest( trunc( add_months( first_date, level - 1 ),'MM'), first_date ) 
           as first_date,
        least( trunc( add_months( first_date, level ),'MM')-1, last_date ) 
           as last_date,
        trunc( add_months( first_date, level ),'MM')-1 as period,
        outstanding
FROM my_query_result t
connect by level <= months_between( trunc(last_date,'MM'), trunc(first_date,'MM') ) + 1;
```

A side note: April has only 30 days, so a date `31/04/2015` in your question is wrong.

Comment: that solve my problem, you're my hero, for now, thank you